Overriding the express Request body type from any to unknown
I am reading up on ambient modules and declaration-merging and I am trying to override the Express TypeScript definition file for Request.
I can add additional properties, but I cannot seem to override the existing properties.
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request extends Record<string, unknown> {
      addition: "a" | "b";
      body: unknown;
      cookies: unknown;
      route: unknown;
      signedCookies: unknown;
    }
  }
}

// type hinting with "a" | "b"
let addition = express.req.addition

// still any
let overridden = express.req.body


Plenty of questions show how to augment, but not override.
I also tried the following:
declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request extends Record<string, unknown> {
      addition: "a" | "b";
      body: unknown;
    }
  }
}


This is an interesting question. Looks like you can't override it, only overload a function or add a property. As per docs: The compiler will issue an error if the interfaces both declare a non-function member of the same name, but of different types. (Funny enough it does not throw an error when you put a different type for the body object, just ignores it for whatever reason).
Narrowing down the type may break the compatibility with other libraries, though.

Yes I read that and wondered why I didn't get any error. I may be attempting to override the wrong definition, since it appears newer version of express use express-service-static-core

It's merging the declarations, and when you merge any with anything else the result is... any https://tsplay.dev/w1D9lW

@jonrsharpe Thank you. I just hoped there might be some way since the very underlying types (unless I am mistaken) are simply empty objects but I guess the Request namespace declaration merging within Express itself using any is causing the issue

Let's override Request interface by redeclare express module, and remember to make your type definition file become a module:
declare module 'express' {
  interface Request {
    addition: "a" | "b";
    body: unknown;
    cookies: unknown;
    route: unknown;
    signedCookies: unknown;
  }
}

export {}; // magic

